# How to include multiple where conditions using Icriteria in nhibernate

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, hql, icriteria

i am developing an application in MVC3 using nhibernate
I have a two tables and i want to perform a join between the two and also i want to include multiple where conditions..
I am posting all the tables that are related so that it will clear the requirements:

```
First table is HobbyMaster:
HobbyId
HobbyName

Second Table is HobbyHome:
HobbyHomeId
HobbyHomeName

Third Table is HobbyDetail:
HobbyDetailId
HobbyId(Foreign Key)
HobbyHomeId(Foreign key)

Fourth Table is HobbyHomeAddress:
Id(primary key)
HobbyHomeId(Foreign key)
StateId(Foreign Key)
DistrictId(Foreign key)

Fifth Table is State:
stateid
statename

last Table is District:
districtid
districtname
```

I want to write a query like this:

```
select * from HobbyHomeAddress hobadd,
              HobbyDetail hobdet 
 where hobdet.HobbyId=hobbyid 
   and hobadd.HobbyId=hobdet.HobbyId 
   and hobadd.StateId=stateid;
```

I tried this  but it is not working and also gives me NUll

```
 hobbyhomeaddress = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(HobbyHomeAddress))
               .CreateAlias("HobbyDetail", "HobbyDetail", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
               .Add(Expression.Eq("HobbyID", hobbyid))
               .Add(Restrictions.Eq("HobbyHomeAddress.HobbyHomeId", "HobbyDetail.HobbyHomeId"))
               .Add(Expression.Eq("ProvincialState.ProvincialStateID", stateid))
               .List<HobbyHomeAddress>();
```

i am able to obtain the id's through ajax but i am not understanding how to fire the following query
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue:

```
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("HobbyHomeAddress.HobbyHomeId", "HobbyDetail.HobbyHomeId"))
```

This part of the join (in SQL) should be in your nhibernate mappings, you don't need to explicitly specify it.